# How to get &#8212 to display as an em dash when interpolating

Tags: vue.js

On a page I'm working on, I'm trying to get the title of a blog post to read as `Sleep—It's frustratingly Important.`, where there is an em dash between `Sleep` and `It's`. Previously I had this hard-coded as

```
<h2 class="post-title"><router-link to="/posts/1">Sleep&#8212It's frustratingly Important. </router-link></h2>
```

which was working fine. I want to generalize this, so in my Rails back end I have the post title stored as `Sleep&#8212It's frustratingly Important.`. But when I insert the post title via interpolation

```
<h2 class="post-title"><router-link to="/posts/1"> {{ this.posts[0].title }} </router-link></h2>
```

It doesn't insert the em dash. It displays as "Sleep&#8212It's frustratingly Important."

Why isn't the html recognizing that &#8212 should be changed to an em dash? And how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content between `{{` and `}}` is expected to be an expression that resolves as plain text. It gets converted into a text node. It does not get treated as HTML.

If you want an em-dash, then use a real em-dash: `—`.

You could also look at [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), but it is named that way for a reason.

Comment: To clarify, "use a real em-dash" means e.g. copy/paste the em dash into wherever your text is stored. `&#8212;` is HTML, not plain text.